# Meteor: Can’t get updates to Android Emulator (Hot Code Push)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, meteor, genymotion

I'm doing mobile development on an Android Emulator with Genymotion. I can't get any code changes to show up on the emulator. I always get this error, even on Startup:

`Skipping downloading new version because the Cordova platform version or plugin versions have changed and are potentially incompatible`

I know this a protection mechanism from bad updates, but It happens all the time. I can't even make a small CSS or JS change. They all get blocked. I tried it on Android 4.4.4, 5.0 and 6.0.

I'm using `Meteor 1.4.1.2` and I simply run `meteor run android-device` and it pops up on the Genymotion device.

Anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: Did you use an older version of Meteor with this app in the past? If so, try to uninstall the app from the emulator device.

Comment: I don't think I have. I tried that. I removed the app, reset app settings, removed the device from genymotion and re added it. Nothing worked. I'll try it on a totally new device

Comment: I downloaded a totally new device from Genymotion and it's still the same thing! When it ran it on the totally new device, it had old files that aren't in my project anymore, or background colors that are different. It's like it's serving up a cached version of the Android build and won't get the new one. I think removing the android platform from my project and re adding it would update the files, but then it still blocks new ones all over again. Very weird.